# Connection refused with mercurial through Kallithea

Tags: git, mercurial, centos, kallithea

I have been working on a server repository running through `Centos 7`, I installed `mercurial` and `Kallithea` and make the proper configuration to launch through apache and all correct, the problem is as follows, always I connect from Mac OS X, my machine, and execute a `hg clone {url}\{repo_name}` I get a nice `abort: error: Connection refused` first of all, this cannot be a problem of firewall or credentials because is properly configured and I try in another machine, specifically, a VM with `Windows 8.1` and there's no problem of cloning/commit/pushing at all, in some way it must be a problem with mercurial (with git repos I have no problem of cloning) What could be wrong? I don't know where to search for an specific log for that matter and this error is driving me nuts all the week...

Regards!

Comment: Mind that "\" is NOT a valid path separator under any OS other than windows. Better ALWAYS use "/" as path separator. If fixing your clone path does not work, then: Do you connect by the same means and do you use (if applicable) the same credentials? If using ssh, is the key automatically supplied?

Comment: Sorry, mistyping, always I type "/" and yes, I use the same credentials and no, key is not automatically supplied when a ssh request is done, anyway,  I get through ssh a `remote: abort: there is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!` not configure that part for manage ssh request through mercurial I guess... now I'm trying to make an `hg clone` from other machine through `http://` and no problem...